# I want to make vertical menu like this (See image for reference

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, submenu

I want to create a vertical drop-down menu. I'm using the list group and list group item class from Bootstrap. Anyone can help me, how can I open the submenu by clicking an item and it should be open in the same div which has a black border. Someone can help me how can I do it?

[My menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuJYR.png)

[I want this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbiZr.png)

Here is my HTML and CSS code.

**HTML**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

function PostAdForm() {
    return (
        <div className="container postAd-container text-center">
            <h6 className="text-left p-3">CHOOSE A CATEGORY</h6>
            <ul className="list-group w-50">
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Mobiles
    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Vehciles
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Property for Sale
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Property for Rent
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Electronics & Home Appliances
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Bikes
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Business, Industrial & Agriculture
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Services
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Jobs
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Animals
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Furniture & Home Decor
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Fashion & Beauty
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Books, Sports & Hobbies
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>                </li>
                <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Kids
                    <span className="badge badge-pill">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </span>                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PostAdForm;
```

**CSS**

```
.postAd-container {
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 1px solid #6c757d;
  width: 70% !important;
}

.list-group {}
.list-group-item {
  color: #6c757d !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.list-group .list-group-item:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,47,52,.2) !important;
  color: #000 !important;
}



.fa-chevron-right {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  color: #6c757d !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider.

#1 Use FA library for icons. (I have added my own CDN hosted snippet for the demo)

#2 Use jQuery to control the opening and closing of the slider.

I built a raw demo for you to play with and then implement in your own case study, with comments

```js
$('.primary-i').click(function() {
  $('.secondary').toggleClass('open'); //this adds the class .open or removes it if its already there (thus closing and opening the .secondary class element by reducing its width back to 0 or augmenting it to 180px //
  });
```

```css
nav {
  position:relative;
}

.primary-i {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.primary, .secondary {
  width:180px;
}

.primary-i, .secondary-i {
  display:flex;border:1px solid black;
  padding:4px;width:150px;
}

.primary-i i:nth-child(1), .secondary-i i:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right:10px;
}

.primary-i i:nth-child(3),  .secondary-i i:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left:70px;
}
  

.secondary {
  width:0!important;overflow-x:hidden;
}.secondary.open {
  width:180px!important;transition:0.5s ease;
}

.secondary {
  position:absolute;top:0;left:158px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-9ZfPnbegQSumzaE7mks2IYgHoayLtuto3AS6ieArECeaR8nCfliJVuLh/GaQ1gyM" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav>
  <div class="primary">
    <div class="primary-i">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span>Item</span>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="primary-i">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span>Item</span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="primary-i">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span>Item</span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </div>
      <div class="secondary">
        <div class="secondary-i">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span>Item</span>
      </div>
        <div class="secondary-i">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span>Item</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Codepen to play with : https://codepen.io/thewhitegrizzzzli/pen/qBNNNgG

Comment: It is working fine but it opens the same sub-menu whenever I click on the items in your code.

Comment: Yes it's just a demo code. Do you need more help with the javascript part? I mean to implement more than one sub-menu?

Comment: No. I mean there are 3 items in your nav and when I click on these items it opens the same sub-menu in all of them.